# What is the term for words that have a hyphen between them?

Tags: grammar, terminology

For example: "indisputably-accurate"; "the quickly-ran event"; "the truck-driving man"; "the under-slept woman"; "the power-possessing orb".

What is the term for the words that surround the hyphen?

Comment: Well, one word for what you have written there is ***WRONG***.  First, you never use a hyphen with an -ly adverb to connect it to its adjective.  Second, the past participle of *run* is *run*, not *ran*.  Third, the word is *underslept* without any hyphen at all.

Comment: *underslept* isn't a word...

Comment: Nonsense! I have an OED and know how to use it: **underˈslept,** *ppl. a.* Etymology: **under** ¹ 10a: cf. **undersleep** *vb.* Having had insufficient sleep; suffering from or characterized by lack of sleep. §1943 *Our Towns* (Women’s Group on Public Welfare) ii. 23 ― It has become a commonplace to say that the town child is underslept. §1966 K. Amis *Anti-Death League* ɪɪɪ. 340 ― Lucy took an illustrated magazine to Churchill’s bed‐side, but she too was underslept, and in a few minutes she nodded off. 
§1981 P. Shea *Voices & Sound of Drums* ii. 14 ― A neglected, underslept appearance.

Comment: Sorry, but [it is a word](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/underslept): see the "Related Forms" section at the bottom. tchrist used it, and I would use it in the same way I'd use "overslept": "I overslept three hours this morning, so I was late to work" and "I underslept three hours this morning, so I'm wasted at the moment".

Comment: @tchrist: "The vagrant was wakened by the traffic on the underslept highway bridge."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first two cases:

> "indisputably-accurate" and "the quickly-ran event"

the only word is "**incorrect**". Never use a hyphen between an adverb of manner ending in /-ly/ and the word that follows. You can find that rule in any manual that explains how to use hyphens.

In the next two cases:

> "the truck-driving man" and "the power-possessing orb"

the word is "**hyphenated**".

In the final case:

> "the under-slept woman"

the word is "**What does this mean?**" Should this be "sleep-deprived"?

Comment: I see you’ve deftly avoided the *only-begotten son* problem. :)

Comment: I was trying to think off the top of my head. Didn't come out right as I can see now.

Comment: @tchrist: That may be one of those petrified expressions that cannot be changed because it's [grandfathered](http://thepreachingwork.xanga.com/673140934/item/) in. Is it used anywhere other than Biblical commentary?

Comment: @tchrist  That hyphen is a vulgar modern intrusion - see [here](http://archive.org/stream/holybiblefacsimi00polluoft#page/n1467/mode/2up)

Answer (score 9):

The examples in which the hyphen is used appropriately are called compound adjectives (or compound modifiers). The hyphenated phrase serves to describe a noun. As everyone else has pointed out, don't use hyphens with -ly adverbs.

This term does not describe all hyphenated phrases, however. *Test-drive* is a transitive verb; *pattern-seeking* is a gerund.

Answer (score 7):

I found this at http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/compadjterm.htm  and thought it might be germane to the topic.

"Interestingly, hyphenation is also used creatively to indicate that an idea that would normally be expressed by a phrase is being treated as a single word for communicative purposes because it has crystallised in the writer's mind into a firm, single concept. Thus, for example, the expression simple to serve is normally a phrase, just like easy to control. But it can also be used as a hyphenated word as in simple-to-serve recipe dishes (M&S Magazine 1992: 9). . . .

"But for creative hyphenation you are unlikely to find anything more striking than this:
[2.3] On Pitcairn there is little evidence of the what-we-have-we-hold, no-surrender, the Queen's-picture-in-every-room sort of attitude.
(Simon Winchester in The Guardian magazine, 12 June 1993: 27; italic added to highlight the compounds)"
(Francis Katamba, English Words: Structure, History, Usage, 2nd ed. Routledge, 2005)

"Adverbs that do not end in -ly may take the hyphen to form a compound adjective. The reason is obvious. A fast-moving script suggests a roller coaster plot while a fast moving script might have pace but it is emotionally charged (i.e., emotionally moving) at the same time."
(Bruce Grundy, So You Want to be a Journalist? Cambridge University Press, 2007)
Also Known As: phrasal adjective